# How to add a new button beside existing one that does not have an ID

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to add a new button object beside an already existing one, but it has no ID so I cannot simple select that object.  The only object with an ID is the iframe.  The page looks like this:

```
<iframe id="gsft_main" />
  <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
      <table>
      ...
      </table>
      <table>
        <table>
        ...
        </table>
      </table>
      <button onclick="someCodeHere('')"> Submit </button>
      <script>...</script>
      <script>...</script>
      <script>...</script>
    <body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

I need to change it so it looks like:

```
...
...
<button onclick="injectedCodeHere('')"> Do Something Else </button>
<button onclick="someCodeHere('')"> Submit </button>
...
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is the last button on the page, select all elements of type `button` and then take the last one from the array:

```
var frame = ... get frame by id ...
var buttons = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName ('button');
var lastButton = buttons[buttons.length-1];
```

Comment: This definitely got me pushed in the right direction.  I was finally able to find a prototypejs snippet that help me out:

`var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var newButton = "<button onclick=\"if (confirm('Are you sure you want to reset?')==true) {window.top.location=window.top.location;window.top.location.href=window.top.location.href;}\"> Reset </button>";
buttons[buttons.length-1].insert({'before' : newButton});
`

Answer (score 1):

This will add a button to the page:

```
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.setAttribute("type", "button");
element.setAttribute("value", "Do Something Else");
element.setAttribute("onclick", "injectedCodeHere('')");

var gsft = document.getElementByID("gsft_main");
gsft.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].appendChild(element);
```

Comment: That worked somewhat, but it actually added the new button inside the last button.  Really weird.